# Do Actions on Google support Chinese?

Tags: actions-on-google

When creating actions on API.AI, we can select Chinese for the agent language and use Chinese words in intents.

But when inputting Chinese in web simulator, it seems not recognized by the action.

Does it mean Chinese is not supported yet?

Is there any plan to support Chinese in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Google Home (and the emulator) only support US English.

Presumably, after official support for the Google Home arrives in other countries and with other languages, Action support will as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Actions for Google Assistant are supported by multiple languages, with their own locales. Chinese, however, is not an option as of yet.

[Here is a list of supported languages and locales.](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales)

Answer (score 2):

Chinese (Traditional) has been added as one of the supported languages:

https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales#chinese_traditional